# React - Use nested map functions in render function to create a 2D board/grid

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, grid, array.prototype.map

I am still kind of new to React and I am working on creating a John Conway's Game of Life project. I am attempting to create a 2D grid of squares to serve as my game's board.

My approach is to use the map function within the render/return to create a grid. I have a Square.js component that consists of this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Square = () => {
  return (

      <td className="Square"></td>

  );
}

export default Square;
```

Then in my App.js I am attempting to use nested .map functions to create the 2D grid of squares. I have successfully created a set of squares going horizontal but I am struggling on nesting two .map functions to create a grid.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boardHeight: 10,
      boardWidth: 50
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table-board">
          <tbody>
            {Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(1).map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <Square key={i} />
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is what I have so far](https://fcc-game-of-life.surge.sh/). If I wrap the  component in a table row like so `<tr><Square key={i} /></tr>` I can make the grid go vertical.

How can I nested two .map functions to make the grid 2D?

This is what I've tried but I can't get it to work:

```
  return (
      <div>
        <table className="table-board">
          <tbody>
            {Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(1).map((el, i) => {
              {Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(1).map((el, j) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <tr><Square key={j} /></tr>
                    <Square key={i} />
                  </div>

                );
              })}

            })}
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: can you post what do you want to render?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can basically map per row and it will be easier. Don't forget to bind the methods in your constructor.

```
renderRow(el, i) {
    return <tr key={i}> {Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(1).map(this.renderColumns)} </tr>
}

renderColumn(el, j) {
    return <Square key={j} />
}

render() {
    return {Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(1).map(this.renderRow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bad requirements

You should treat react component as view - to **render state of given (passed as prop) array - not creating this during render methods/calls!**

Create an array at start (constructor) and use indexes of `map` functions to read "cells/fields".

**You can use one linear array** - `length=width*height` - single map function in render and use css/styling to wrap them in rows by square and board widths. Board width can be precalculated in constructor (when not changed in lifecycle) - board width = `boardWidth` * square width - and passed in JSX.

Of course **you can use two `map` functions** to create 2D board. It can be used for rendering using `<table/>` and `<tr/><td>` html structure or for performance reasons. With second option create separate  component and pass part of data as prop - **it (almost) doesn't matter if it will be a separate array (better) or range from linear array - internally `Row` will be working on one simple array** (and one `map` fn). It should depend on engine requirements.

**Look for inspirations [here](https://github.com/willb335/chessboardjsx).** You have simpler case - you don't have to return events/moves.